# How could I put a method parameter in the name of a property at runtime

Tags: c#

I am trying to shorten this method, as there must be a better way to do it.

Where it references the **Public Properties** Line1X, Line1Y, Line2X ... in the case statement, I would like to somehow replace the **1, 2** in these properties at runtime with the variable **lineNo** value to stop the repetition. e.g Line(lineNo)X

```
switch (lineNo)
{
    case "Line 1":
        switch (parameter)
        {
            case "DecX":
                if (Line1X > 0)
                    Line1X -= 1;
                break;
            case "IncX":
                if (Line1X < LabelWidth)
                    Line1X += 1;
                break;
            case "DecY":
                if (Line1Y > 0)
                    Line1Y -= 1;
                break;
            case "IncY":
                if (Line1Y < LabelHeight)
                    Line1Y += 1;
                break;
        }
        break;
    case "Line 2":
        switch (parameter)
        {
            case "DecX":
                if (Line2X > 0)
                    Line2X -= 1;
                break;
            case "IncX":
                if (Line2X < LabelWidth)
                    Line2X += 1;
                break;
            case "DecY":
                if (Line2Y > 0)
                    Line2Y -= 1;
                break;
            case "IncY":
                if (Line2Y < LabelHeight)
                    Line2Y += 1;
                break;
        }
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you use a List to store your lines ? So you can access line numbers by index on the list

Comment: All your cases are equal, they just operate on another variable. Move that to a method and call that method.

Comment: `AdjustLine` is doing too much. And controlling flow by passing strings is really awkward. Is there a specific reason for that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't really understand some of the potential answer here, so after some more searching it looked like I needed to learn Reflection.

Basically I replaced my original question code with the code below and it works exactly how i want it to, cutting down from a ridiculous 228 lines of code to something like 16.

I can probably optimize it further but am happy this now works.

```
public void AdjustLine(string parameter, string line)
    {
        string linePos = line.Replace(" ", "");
        string XorY = string.Empty;

        if (parameter.Contains("X"))
            XorY = "X";
        else if (parameter.Contains("Y"))
            XorY = "Y";

        PropertyInfo propertyInfo = typeof(LabelDesignViewModel).GetProperty(linePos + XorY);

        double propVal = (double)propertyInfo.GetValue(this, null);

        switch (propVal)
        {
            case > 0 when parameter == "DecX":
            case > 0 when parameter == "DecY":
                lineCoord?.SetValue(this, propVal -= 1);
                break;
            default:
                lineCoord?.SetValue(this, propVal += 1);
                break;
        }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You just need to store your lines in an array and use an index to access them e.g.

```
private int[] _xLines = new int[2] { Line1X, Line2X };
private int[] _yLines = new int[2] { Line1Y, Line2Y };

public void AdjustLine(string parameter, int lineNo)
{ 
    switch (parameter)
    {
        case "DecX":
            if (_xLines[lineNo - 1] > 0)
                _xLines[lineNo - 1] -= 1;
            break;
        case "IncX":
            if (_xLines[lineNo - 1] < LabelWidth)
                _xLines[lineNo - 1] += 1;
            break;
        case "DecY":
            if (_yLines[lineNo - 1] > 0)
                _yLines[lineNo - 1] -= 1;
            break;
        case "IncY":
            if (_yLines[lineNo - 1] < LabelHeight)
                _yLines[lineNo - 1] += 1;
            break;
    }
}
```

If you need to add to the number of lines during runtime then you can use a list instead of an array.

Answer (score 0):

YungDeiza was a bit faster then me and I am suggesting nearly the same, but I would use a class together with the array. I would also put the functions into an array ... I am going to come up with an even better code soon:

```
  private class Line
  {
    public Line(Action<int> sx, Func<int> gx, Action<int> sy, Func<int> gy)
    {
      this._SetX = sx;
      this._SetY = sy;
      this._GetX = gx;
      this._GetY = gy;
    }
    private Action<int> _SetX;
    private Action<int> _SetY;
    private Func<int> _GetX;
    private Func<int> _GetY;
    public int X { get { return this._GetX(); } set { this._SetX(value); } }
    public int Y { get { return this._GetY(); } set { this._SetY(value); } }
  }

  private int TryParse(string remove, string text)
  {
    try
    {
      return int.Parse(text.Replace(remove, string.Empty)) - (int)decimal.One;
    }
    catch
    {
      return (int)decimal.MinusOne;
    }
  }

  private void New(string lineNo, string parameter)
  {
    // using System;
    // using System.Collections.Generic;
    int lineIndex = TryParse("Line ", lineNo);

    Dictionary<string, Action<Line>> funktions = new Dictionary<string, Action<Line>>();
    funktions.Add("DecX", l => { if (l.X > decimal.Zero) l.X--; });
    funktions.Add("IncX", l => { if (l.X < this.LabelWidth) l.X++; });
    funktions.Add("DecY", l => { if (l.Y > decimal.Zero) l.Y--; });
    funktions.Add("IncY", l => { if (l.Y < this.LabelHeight) l.Y++; });

    List<Line> lines = new List<Line>();
    lines.Add(new Line(i => this.Line1X = i, () => this.Line1X, i => this.Line1Y = i, () => this.Line1Y));
    lines.Add(new Line(i => this.Line2X = i, () => this.Line2X, i => this.Line2Y = i, () => this.Line2Y));

    if (funktions.ContainsKey(parameter) && lineIndex > decimal.Zero && lineIndex < lines.Count)
      funktions[parameter](lines[lineIndex]);
    else
      return; // what ever happesn if lineNo or parameter are not correct
  }
```

Greetings

Juy Juka

PS: Here some more - perhaps better code - using methods in the line class instead of a dictionary with a string as a key.

```
  private class Line
  {
    public Line(Y o, Action<int> sx, Func<int> gx, Action<int> sy, Func<int> gy) { this._SetX = sx; this._SetY = sy; this._GetX = gx; this._GetY = gy; this.o = o; }
    private Y o;
    private Action<int> _SetX;
    private Action<int> _SetY;
    private Func<int> _GetX;
    private Func<int> _GetY;
    public int X { get { return this._GetX(); } set { this._SetX(value); } }
    public int Y { get { return this._GetY(); } set { this._SetY(value); } }

    public virtual void DecX() { if (this.X > decimal.Zero) this.X--; }
    public virtual void IncX() { if (this.X < this.o.LabelWidth) this.X--; }
    public virtual void DecY() { if (this.X > decimal.Zero) this.X--; }
    public virtual void IncY() { if (this.Y < this.o.LabelHeight) this.X--; }
  }

  private void New(string lineNo, string parameter)
  {
    // using System;
    // using System.Collections.Generic;
    List<Line> lines = new List<Line>();
    lines.Add(new Line(this, i => this.Line1X = i, () => this.Line1X, i => this.Line1Y = i, () => this.Line1Y));
    lines.Add(new Line(this, i => this.Line2X = i, () => this.Line2X, i => this.Line2Y = i, () => this.Line2Y));

    int lineIndex;
    if (!int.TryParse((lineNo ?? string.Empty).Replace("Line ", string.Empty), out lineIndex)) lineIndex = (int)decimal.MinusOne;
    else lineIndex--;
    if (lineIndex < decimal.Zero || lineIndex > lines.Count) return; // or what ever you do on a worong line number

    System.Reflection.MethodInfo method = typeof(Line).GetMethod(parameter);
    if (method == null) return; // or what ever you do on a worong paraemter

    method.Invoke(lines[lineIndex], new object[] { });
  }
```